# k-means for all data or for each feature?

Tags: time-series, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want use [k-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) to discretize a time series data in two values (0 or 1). My time series data is a matrix time per genes (line = time, column = gene). Ex:

```
t\x   x1    x2    x3
 1  0.122 0.324 0.723
 2  0.543 0.573 0.329
 3  0.901 0.445 0.343
 4  0.612 0.353 0.435
 5  0.192 0.233 0.023
```

My question: Should I use **k clusters for all data of matrix** or **k clusters for each column** (so I will have k cluster per column totalizing k.number_columns)? and my genes are independents

Answer (score 0):

Either may work.

Discretising all attributes at once has the benefit of giving you only one symbol per time, i.e. a univariate series.

But on the other hand, if columns are independent, the quality could be better if you discretise them individually. Note thatfor one-dimensional data, if it is noisy, quantiles may be much better than k-means (which is sensitive to noise).

Comment: Thank you. I was doubt about it. I will discretise individually